# Не происходит ререндер компонента при изменении стора после добавления драг'n'дропа

Tags: javascript, reactjs, компоненты

Всем привет, возникла такая проблема: есть список элементов с драг н дропом, при добавлении в него нового элемента не происходит ререндер компонента (в стор все приходит)  P.S.  до добавления днд все работало номрально.

код здесь:
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-hill-nsi55?file=/src/index.js

Comment: до добавления днд все работало номрально(С) - так выброси её

Comment: Перенесите ваш код в любую из js песочниц и прикрепите ссылку

Comment: @Fil Это происходит потому что вы записываете this.props в this.state в constructor, т.е что вы делаете, вы записываете только 1 раз, при инициализации класса. Решение: 1-Хранить список в redux-store и вообще не использовать state(т.е вызывать map сразу для this.props.cams). 2-Использовать различные lifecycle методы react.